# How to integrate swagger in apache cxf jax-rest api in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

How to integrate swagger ui in apache cxf jax-rest api in spring boot application?

Comment: Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Questions like these are too broad for this site. You'll find whole blogs and manuals dedicated to answering this question.

Comment: This is covered in many tutorials so you need to explain what specific issue you ran into.

Comment: Disagree on downvotes. Maybe question is too broad, but it's useful, concrete, related to specific technologies and have definitive answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm editing a blog post with a demo, actually the demo is completed about this exact topic and here is an excerpt of the source code:

Edited: Just published [Implementing APIs using Spring Boot, CXF and Swagger](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/06/12/Implementing-APIs-using-Spring-Boot-CXF-and-Swagger.html)

**pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Main class:

**DemoCxfApplication.java**:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.example.demo.rest" })
public class DemoCxfApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoCxfApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration classes:

**FeaturesConfig.java**:

```
package com.example.demo.rest.config;
...
@Configuration
public class FeaturesConfig {

    @Value("${cxf.path}")
    private String basePath;

    @Bean("swagger2Feature")
    public Feature swagger2Feature() {
        Swagger2Feature result = new Swagger2Feature();
        result.setTitle("Spring Boot + CXF + Swagger + Docker Example");
        result.setDescription("Spring Boot + CXF + Swagger + Docker Example description");
        result.setBasePath(this.basePath);
        result.setVersion("v1");
        result.setSchemes(new String[] { "http", "https" });
        result.setPrettyPrint(true);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**ProvidersConfig.java**:

```
package com.example.demo.rest.config;
...
@Provider
@Configuration
public class ProvidersConfig {

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider() {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }
}
```

Resource interface and implementation:

**HelloResource.java**

```
package com.example.demo.rest.v1;
...
@Path("/")
@Api(value = "Hello resource Version 1", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Path("v1/hello/{name}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets a hello resource. Version 1 - (version in URL)")
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Hello resource found", response = Hello.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Hello resource not found")
    })
    Response getHelloVersionInUrl(@PathParam("name") @ApiParam(value = "The name") String name);
...
}
```

**HelloResourceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.demo.rest.v1.impl;
...
// No JAX-RS annotation in class, method or method arguments
@Component("helloResourceV1")
public class HelloResourceImpl implements HelloResource {

    @Override
    public Response getHelloVersionInUrl(String name) {
        LOGGER.info("getHelloVersionInUrl() v1");
        return this.getHello(name, "Version 1 - passed in URL");
    }
...
}
```

Properties file:

**application.yml**

```
# Spring MVC dispatcher servlet path. Needs to be different than CXF's to enable/disable Actuator endpoints access (/info, /health, ...)
server.servlet-path: /

management.security.enabled: false

# http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html#SpringBoot-SpringBootCXFJAX-RSStarter
cxf:
  path: /api # CXFServlet URL pattern
  jaxrs:
    component-scan: true
```

`Swagger UI` available at: `http://<host:port>/api/api-docs?url=/api/swagger.json`

`WADL` available at: `http://<host:port>/api?_wadl`

Comment: Hi, I have implemented a similar example and I am accessing the Swagger UI in 
http://<host:port>/api/api-docs?url=/api/swagger.json . When i try to access 
http://<host:port>/api/api-docs? I am getting a demo page of the swagger (Swagger Petstore). I would really like to access the Swagger UI documentation of my api on http://<host:port>/api/api-docs? instead of the demo page, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: can you please share the version of the above example written in bean.xml configuration style